# cannot login after upgrade to 21.10

Tags: login, 21.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu 21.04 to 21.10, the login widget (the one with my username where I can type my password) no longer shows up when I start the computer.

If I push `ctrl + alt +F5` , I see 3 lines of error messages, something about `rtl_usb reg0x80 usbctrl_vendor req timeout`, `rtl8192c_common is not ready to run`, and the network not being available.
I don't get a prompt to type in my username and password.

If I reboot in recovery mode, I get the same symptoms in the GUI mode (no way to log in), but with  `ctrl + alt + F5` I can now log-in and type `startx` . After that everything works as normal, until I reboot.

I tried reinstalling from scratch, in case this was caused by me fiddling with configuration files in the past. But I get the same symptoms with a fresh install.

EDIT: just to be clear, I don't get a login widget but I'm in some sort of GUI environment. I can click on the date and get a calender (top middle of the screen), and I can access the "shutwodn / sleep : reboot" menu (top right of the screen). And those tools are working. But the rest of the screen is just the purple background image, I'm  missing any way to select my username and type in my password.

Comment: At this point I'm ready to downgrade back to 21.04 if that fixes my issue. Is this even possible? I would like to avoid another install from scratch (tired of doing backups and then having to restore my entire work environment).

Comment: No you cannot downgrade and 21.04 will be EOL soon.  Are you sure that your reinstall was a clean installation and that you didn't just install on top of your existing installation?  Are you also sure your installation media is valid and passes all integrity checks? You could also install 20.04, which as an LTS is naturally more stable and has 5 years of support instead of 9 months for standard releases.

Comment: Give this a goi. Get yourself logged-in using you r start-x method and then open a terminal. Tyle `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target`and then reboot.

Comment: @darth_epoxy I was able to reboot once after that command (but that happened a couple of times before  also, after rebooting in recovery mode), then the same symptoms are back. Except the error message changed when trying `ctrl + alt + F5`: 
`failed to Start Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled` (repeated multiple times)

Comment: After a couple of reboots, I 'm back to my same old errors messages about the usb network devices.

Comment: What is the result of this terminal command `env | grep XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` please? And have you tried rebooting with all USB peripherals removed?

Comment: `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a proper software solution to fix this bug. But I can now boot my computer "normally" by initially unplugging the USB wifi adapter, and plugging it back in only after I have reached the login screen.